# Cached Network Image and Photo View : The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following piece of code using advanced_network_image_2(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage_2) with photo_view(https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view).

I need to transform it to using Cached Network Image.However I'm getting the said error.

Here is the code.

```html
Widget _getPositionedZoomableImage() {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Positioned(
      top: _posY != 0 ? _posY : 0,
      left: _posX != 0 ? _posX : 0,
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenHeight,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: _rotationAngle,
        child: PhotoView(
          backgroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
          key: Key(widget.imageUrl),
          enableRotation: false,
          scaleStateChangedCallback: _photoViewScaleStateChangedCallback,
          imageProvider: AdvancedNetworkImage(widget.imageUrl,
              retryLimit: 0, useDiskCache: true, getRealUrl: () {
            return Future.delayed(
                (const Duration(milliseconds: 0)), () => widget.imageUrl);
          },
              cacheRule: const CacheRule(
                maxAge: Duration(days: 7),
                checksum: true,
              ),
              fallbackAssetImage: 'assets/images/fallbacks/post-fallback.png'),
          maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
          minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What's the right way to tranform the above code to using Cached Network Image.

My reasons for transforming are :

1. advanced_network_image_2 is not updated since 22 months
2. It has dependency issues with one of my other packages flutter_svg and I'm forced to use a very old version of flutter_svg with advanced_network_image_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use the Cached Network Image package. Pretty useful.

```
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      //key: Key(path.basename(imageUrl!)),
      //height: 116,
      //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: imageProvider,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      //fit: BoxFit.cover,
      placeholder: (context, url) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
        return Center(child: Icon(PhosphorIcons.bold.fileX));
      }, // NULL
    );
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.